# Makefile for multiple executables with common files

Tags: c, makefile

I need help in writing a makefile that creates two separate executables that depend on a common file. So, I have three source files: Master.c Common.c Worker.c, and three corresponding header files. Now, Master.c includes Master.h and Common.h. Similarly, Worker.c includes Worker.h and Common.h. I would like to create two executables, namely Master and Worker, using the same makefile. I have the following makefile, but it's not functioning properly because for each global variable declared in Common.h, I get the error **"Multiple declarations"** when I type *make*. Note that I do use #indef, #define, and #endif in all the header files.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS= -g -I -pthread -lpthread -std=c99
DEPS = Common.h
OBJ1 = Master.o Common.o 
OBJ2 = Worker.o Common.o 

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
     $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

all: Master Worker

Master: $(OBJ1)
     gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

Worker: $(OBJ2)
     gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean:
        rm -f *.o
```

Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the definitions of global variables into headers; instead, put them in one of the source files and only *declare* the variables in the header:

**Common.h:**

```
extern int foo;    /* declaration only */
```

**Common.c:**

```
#include "Common.h"

int foo;           /* definition */
```

Otherwise including the header in more than one translation unit violates the one-definition rule.

Comment: Can't I put the declarations in Common.c? I did try doing so and I get the error "undeclared variables".

Comment: @NewToAndroid: Didn't you just answer your own question?!

Comment: One last question..is the makefile above flawless?

Comment: @NewToAndroid, I post an answer to your "flawless" question

Answer (score 0):

> is the makefile above flawless?

No.  I can see several issues, if you fix them then it would be "state-of-the-art":

1. (a bug) all targets should at least depend on `$(MAKEFILE)`

   `MAKEFILE := $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))`

   you will then also need to filter the `$^` in the recipe: `$(filter %.o, $^)`, which is a good practice anyway
2. use `:=` instead of `=`, it is more efficient and makes the logic in your code easier to understand in general, should always be used by default, unless `=` is necessary
3. you are defining `CC` to be `gcc` then not using it but using `gcc` instead
4. consider generating dependencies automatically (grep the manual), in this small case not needed perhaps, but for a larger case you will need it - there is good support in `gcc` for that nowadays
5. use a "canned recipe" (grep the manual) for the repeating recipe
6. `.PHONY: all clean`
7. `clean` does not remove everything